# It doesn't give me the variable length error in Mysql and I can't rollback in my program

Tags: mysql, varchar

This is my table 'persona'
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3BoT.png)

The 'apellido' field is 10 characters long.
However when I add a new record with more characters in that field ...
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1U8V5.png)

It does not give me the error that it should give me, as the data is longer than what the field allows.
In addition to registering the wrong data with the 10 characters that the field allows ...
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0fUW.png)

Consequently my program cannot rollback when a wrong data is written in that field because Mysql does not consider it an error.
Try modifying the autocommit:
SET autocommit = OFF
But the problem persists
Can you help me understand this problem please, I would greatly appreciate it. Greetings community.

Comment: You get a warning when the data has been truncated (error code 1265). You can check for warnings in your query. Or do you want to do something different?

Comment: thank you i have to modifycate the my.ini file and put sql_mode=STRICT_ALL_TABLES for now is runnig thank you <3